# jQuery inline table editing & update mysql via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using gijgo --> [http://gijgo.com](http://gijgo.com/) with jQuery and there is an ajax example for updating table inline: http://gijgo.com/Grid/Demos/InlineEdit

What I need to do to parse ajax results and update mysql table using php?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea of what to do... :(

Comment: Could you at least provide what results, what are you trying to achieve or what you have in mind? Have you look in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)